# django 2.2.4 from __future__ import unicode_literals

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django version 2.2.4 with the code below. In terminal I'm not getting any error messages, however, after creating a new profile in the admin section, instead of displaying the name of the new profile 'profile Object 1' is displayed. 'return self.name' is suppose to get the name from the newly created profile and display it. Please view picture for a clear understanding.

[image]

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(default='description default text')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `unicode_literals` and `def __unicode__` are only relevant in Python 2. Django 2.X does not support Python < 3.4, so both are useless. Simply implement `__str__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with unicode_literals.

The name of the method should be `__str__`, not `__unicode__`.

Comment: OP missed the fact that Django 2.X does not even support Python 2 (both `unicode_literals` and `__unicode__` are from the Python 2 days)

Comment: Is there a method I can use to fix this compatibility issue ? I'm a newbie to python and following a tutorial

Comment: @user3574939 Like I wrote in the other comment, there is no "compatibility issue". Your Django version does not support Python 2 at all

Comment: i now understand that unicode_literals is not support in python 3, but is there away to get the name used to create a new profile to display rather than  Profile object (1) using python 3 ?

Comment: @user3574939 Both this answer and my comment under the question explain how to fix that